# Конфликт версий у зависимости библиотеки Composer и зависимости основного проекта

Tags: php, composer

Здравствуйте. Разрабатываю библиотеку, которая в качестве зависимости использует Guzzle. Guzzle - довольно популярная библиотека, поэтому вероятность, что мою библиотеку подключат в проект, где уже используется этот HTTP-клиент (или наоборот) относительно велика. Текущая стабильная версия Guzzle - 6.2.2.

Я с Composer на "вы", так что меня мучают вопросы: что случится, если спустя какое-то время я прекращу поддержку библиотеки? В качестве зависимости у неё так и останется какая-нибудь версия, допустим `^6.2`. Но пройдет время и выйдет седьмая версия Guzzle. Я читал, что Composer не умеет хранить две разные версии одной и той же зависимости. Получается, что либо моя библиотека перестанет работать у пользователя (если в версии 7 изменится API), либо пользователю придется использовать версию `^6.2`? Как эту проблему решают разработчики библиотек?

Благодарю за ответы и извиняюсь за заголовок, который я не смог внятно сформулировать.

Comment: Вы можете ввести версионность и в своей библиотеке, тогда одна версия вашей библиотеки будет поддерживать одну версию guzzle, а другая другую. тем более ведь версии не просто так даются. фиксятся баги, улучшается функционал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь зависит от того насколько несовместимой стала новая мажорная версия Guzzle.

1. Изменения совершенно не сломали вашу совместимость - тогда в composer'е вы ставитте `guzzle/guzzle: ~6.0|~7.0`
2. Изменения сломали вашу совместимость - тогда вы выпускаете свою новую мажорную версию, которая использует новую мажорную версию библиотеки

Если вы вдруг перестали поддерживать свою библиотеку, то обязательно найдутся умельцы, которые готовы кидать вам pull-реквесты с исправлением багов, добавлением новых фич и изменениями для работы с новой мажорной версией библиотеки используемой, вам лишь остается просматривать и принимать реквесты. Или передать управление кому-нибудь другому, решать вам.